# Union of connected sets with possible empty intersection

Tags: metric-spaces, connectedness

There is a result which states that if a collection $A$ of connected sets has a point $P$ belonging to every of those sets, then its union is connected

I was wondering if this remains true if the hypothesis is that for each of those sets $X$ there exists another one $Y_X \in A$ of then such that the intersection of those two is non-empty. With this condition can we conclude that the union is connected?

Comment: No. Take $A=[0,1], B=[1,2],C=[3,4],D=[4,5]$. The union is not connected.

Comment: However, this may sometimes be useful: If the graph with the given connected sets as vertices and an edge between two sets iff they intersect is connected, then the union of our sets is connected ...

Answer (score 0):

No. Take $A=\{\{0\},[0,1],\{2\},[2,3]\}$. Then the union of its elements is $[0,1]\cup[2,3]$, which is not connected.